# Error 000735 when using collect values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator, error-000735

I am using a Feature Class Iterator in a Submodel ending with Collect Features:

[image]

The main model looks like this:

[image]

When I want to run it I only get this error:

[image]

I have no clue why he says the value is empty. 
Does anyone know it?

Comment: The answer below is suggesting that you collect in the master model. This is wrong you collect in the submodel as you were doing in your first image. In your first image the tool that is feeding into collects is white, the problem is with your upstream logic. But as you do not show that it is impossible to comment on.

Comment: No, the upstream logic is not the problem. I've tried that seperatly and it works fine. the only problem left here is the collect value output. And the model is meant to be white like I said below because its a model with variable inputs which can be used for many different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, After understanding the purpose of the merge and collect values of your features.

I would suggest using (Append) tool, which it does your purpose.

So the order must be Output values >> collect value >> as parameter

[image]

Then in the main Model, you add your submodel, (Append) tool and a feature that will be the target

[image]

[image]

This [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm) shows you how to use the only model tools.

This [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm) explains how to use (append).

Comment: http://pro.arcgis.com/de/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/collect-values.htm

here it saysy that merge can be used after collect values?

Comment: @Loki I updated the answer with screenshots that explain how you can make collect value working with submodel and merge. PS: that your  ModelBuilder must be colored not white to run.

Comment: I edited the question 

and the model is white because it should be a model with variables which can be used as cost distance analysis for many different regions

Comment: @Loki Can you explain what do you want to merge exactly so we can define the problem! (what type of values you collect and you want to merge?)

Comment: I put an feature class with three points into the iterate feature class iterator and thus goes into cost distance. Into cost path have to go three other points as destination (but this still does not work with the iterator, I made another question about that.) and then the output are three different polylines each from one start to the matching end point. And with the iterator these are three different feature classes but I need them in one to do further analysis with them. That's why I want to use collect values and merge.

Comment: @Loki I update the answer, in this case you can use Append tool. which it does your purpose. Please note the new order of the modelbuilder

Comment: It actually works now with Collect Values inside the Submodel and Merge in the main model. But sadly only with stable inputs (= coloured model). I'm still working on making it run with variable inputs (= white model).

Comment: @Loki so if the answer helps to solve your question, you can accept it. And you can add another question based on your (white model) if you got stuck with something, maybe we can help.

Comment: I know but the answer now is about the Append tool, thats why I didnt mark it. But it actually works the same way. 
Well, I kind of fixed the white model problem by outsmarting GIS: 
if you first put in stable variables, then put Merge as Input iinto another Tool and then finally delete the stable inputs again, Merge still is the inpt to the other tool. I hope it stays there!